# Svg - realtime scrolling chart

Tags: java, svg

Is it possible to create a realtime scrolling chart with svg in java android?

I found java salamander to display svg, but I don't know how to refresh the contained data on the chart...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I doubt Salamander will work on Android.

The Android WebView supports SVG from Honeycomb onwards.  You could try that.

There are also a few standalone SVG libraries for Android, but none of them support animation or the type of DOM manipulation you are after.

SVG may not be the best solution for this use case.  Drawing the chart yourself with the Android Canvas API would probably be a better approach.